# What is the structure of the following sentence? Is it right to use more than one clause is a sentence without adding linking word?

Tags: sentence-construction

> “A scene of almost unspeakable beauty presented itself, lights of every imaginable colour were issuing from the southern heavens,” he would later recall.

I see here three clauses are added in a one single sentence without even adding no linkers.
How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several remarks can be made here:

The man is talking (it is dialogue) and when you are talking you take all kinds of liberties. So, **he omitted an *and*** conjunction between the two sentences.
**OR**

**You can view this as an apposition**, there are two clauses that are in fact in apposition. The second one **is like** a restatement of the first.

“//A scene of almost unspeakable beauty presented itself//, lights of every imaginable colour were issuing from the southern heavens,” he would later recall.

An apposition in simplest terms is a restatement using a phrase or a clause and is set off by commas.

Most languages allow one to speak without always following some predetermined pattern.

I suggest you translate the sentences into your own language as dialog and you will see that.

Answer (score 0):

> [*"A scene of almost unspeakable beauty presented itself*], [*lights of every imaginable colour were issuing from the southern heavens*],*” he would*
> *later recall*.

The two bracketed clauses are independent (main) ones, so strictly speaking the writer should have transcribed the original utterance using heavier punctuation than a comma to link them. A colon, semicolon or dash would do the trick.

Not a serious error, but easily avoided by a careful writer.